# Doctrine generating query with wrong table alias - Symfony 5

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

I'm trying to insert an user in my database and doctrine generate before this :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.first_name AS first_name_3, t0.username AS username_4, t0.password AS password_5, t0.aRoles AS aRoles_6, t0.create_date AS create_date_7, t8.id AS id_9, t8.name AS name_10, t8.siren AS siren_11, t8.social_network_list AS social_network_list_12, t8.sponso AS sponso_13, t8.created_date AS created_date_14, t8.user_id AS user_id_15 FROM user t0 LEFT JOIN company t8 ON t8.user_id = t16.id WHERE t0.username = ?' with params ["test@gmail.com"]:
```

With the following error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't16.id' in 'on clause'
```

Doctrine creates an alias "t16" but the good alias is "t0"

In my controller, I use a form to manage the user registration.

My user entity is here :

```
**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
* @UniqueEntity(
*     fields={"username"},
*     message="Le compte est existant !"
* )
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Length(min="8", minMessage="Votre mot de passe doit faire au minimum 8 caractères")
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="password", message="Les mots de passes ne sont pas identiques")
 */
public $confirm_password;

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="aRoles", type="array", length=400, nullable=false)
 */
private $aroles;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createDate;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Company::class, mappedBy="user")
 */
private $company;
```

And the company entity :

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CompanyRepository::class)
*/
class Company
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $siren;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $socialNetworkList;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $sponso;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdDate;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=user::class, inversedBy="company")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be related to some misconfiguration. Change your mapping to:

User

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $company;
```

Company (see the caps in User)

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="company")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much. When I created the relationship in the company entity with the console, I think I wrote user in lowercase but I did not have an error during its creation ..

Comment: You are welcome! Could you accept the answer so the question is "solved"?